# Android - unexpected app crash

Tags: android, class, android-manifest

Ok so I have a cocktail bible app that lets you select a cocktail form a list and it should display various information about the cocktail like text,img and a button to link a youtube clip.The code is compiling but when I click on one of the items in the list the app unexpected crashes. Also at the moment my app only allows two cocktail's how would I get it to run 20 cocktails?
I have removed mostly all imports by the way.

Code to run the list class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.Activity;

public class CocktailMenu extends Activity {

    String classes[] = {"Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha", "Cosmopolitan", "Cuba_Libre", "Daiquiri", "Mai_Tai", "Manhattan", "Margarita", "Martini", "Mint_Julep", "Mojito", "Old_Fashoned", "Pina_Colada", "Screwdriver", "Singapore_Sling", "Tom_Collins", "Whiskey_Sour", "White_Russian"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cocktail_menu);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bByList);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRandomCocktail);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    Class<?> menuClass = Class.forName("com.drunktxtapp.Menu");
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(CocktailMenu.this, menuClass);
                    startActivity(ourIntent);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String cocktailType = classes[(int) (Math.random() * classes.length)];
                try{
                Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("com.drunktxtapp." + cocktailType);
                Intent openRandom = new Intent(CocktailMenu.this, ourClass);
                startActivity(openRandom);
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    });
    }
}
```

code that produces a list of cocktails

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;


public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] = {"Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha", "Cosmopolitan", "Cuba_Libre", "Daiquiri", "Mai_Tai", "Manhattan", "Margarita", "Martini", "Mint_Julep", "Mojito", "Old_Fashoned", "Pina_Colada", "Screwdriver", "Singapore_Sling", "Tom_Collins", "Whiskey_Sour", "White_Russian"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);;
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, CocktailDetail.class);
            ourIntent.putExtra("Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha");
            startActivity(ourIntent);
    }
}
```

Code that changes the information of the cocktail display page

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.net.Uri;

public class CocktailDetail extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cocktaildetail);
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCocktail);
        imageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bloodymary));
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bYoutube);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
        String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bloody Mary");
        t1.setText(cocktailName);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alt-ehDc3fc")));
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the LogCat

```
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at com.drunktxtapp.CocktailDetail.onCreate(CocktailDetail.java:26)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
04-18 09:22:38.085: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     ... 11 more
04-18 09:27:46.270: I/Process(1068): Sending signal. PID: 1068 SIG: 9
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/beer"
    android:id="@+id/cocktailDetail" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCocktailName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Cocktail Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCocktail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bloodymary" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textIngredients"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Insert txt here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Preparation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPrepration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Insert txt here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonYoutube"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="YouTube Clip"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: stacktrace from logcat will be more helpful

Comment: Post the stacktrace after the last line u have pasted here...

Comment: Sorry its changed now I'm quite new to all this!

Comment: Do you know how I would go about changing the img,text and youtube clip when an item in the list is clicked. Also the line ourIntent.putExtra("Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha"); only allows me to add two Strings how can I add more than two Strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the Button with the ID "bYoutube" in your xml file. It looks like when you look for that Button, the call returns null, so when you try to set its onClickListener, your app crashes.

Comment: Thank you so much you are a life saver! I'v been trying for hours to find the problem

Comment: Do you know how I would go about changing the img,text and youtube clip when an item in the list is clicked. Also the line ourIntent.putExtra("Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha"); only allows me to add two Strings how can I add more than two Strings?

Comment: First of all, you're using the Intent wrong. The first value in the Intent.putExtra(name, data) call is the NAME of the extra data you're adding. For example, in your case, it might make sense to call it "COCKTAILS". The second value can be various things (check out the Intent documentation) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html but in your case it would make the most sense to pass in an array of the names of your cocktails.

Comment: To change the image, text, whatever, you would probably set whatever values you want for those objects by adding an onItemClickListener to your list and changing all those things in that listener.

Comment: Thanks Catherine..Would the code be somthing similar to this ListView cocktail = getListView();
        cocktail.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             //code to change items here
           }

Comment: Yup, you're on the right path! BTW, if my answer solved your problem, can you set it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Accepted! So would I put a if/else if statment like if(view == bloody_mary){ //code here}else if(view == ...and so on and for the Intent.putExtra should I have it as ourIntent.putExtra("Cocktails", classes[position]);

Comment: Thanks! The onItemClick listener gets the position of the view that was clicked--you should be able to figure out from that which of your items was clicked (`view == bloody_mary` won't work--what is `bloody_mary` in that context anyway? `view` is just the view that was clicked, where are you setting `bloody_mary` to be a view?) For the Intent.putExtra, you can do classes[position] but that will only pass in one cocktail. If you want to pass them all in, just call `ourIntent.putExtra("Cocktails", classes);`

Answer (score 0):

You left the underscore in `Bloody_Mary`

The statement `String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bloody Mary");` must be

`String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bloody_Mary");`

and `Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonYoutube);`

Comment: Do you know how I would go about changing the img,text and youtube clip when an item in the list is clicked. Also the line ourIntent.putExtra("Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha"); only allows me to add two Strings how can I add more than two Strings?

Comment: if you need add a another statement with another key and value `ourIntent.putExtra("Key", "Value");`. I think really u should pass it as `ourIntent.putExtra("SomeKey", classes[position]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYoutube);
```

As there's no `bYoutube` button in your xml file.