# Change TextView when item is clicked on a ListAdapter?

Tags: android, class, android-manifest

I have two classes and a XML. The first one creates an ListApter full of cocktail names like bloody mary,margarita, ect. The second class is set up so I can change the TextView and an Image displayed in the XML. I'm having difficulty trying to pass the item that I'v pressed in the ListAdapter into the CocktailDetail class to change the values of the TextView and the Image. Can anybody help? It runs but opens Bloody mary for every item selected in the list.

Menu class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha", "Cosmopolitan",
            "Cuba_Libre", "Daiquiri", "Mai_Tai", "Manhattan", "Margarita",
            "Martini", "Mint_Julep", "Mojito", "Old_Fashoned", "Pina_Colada",
            "Screwdriver", "Singapore_Sling", "Tom_Collins", "Whiskey_Sour",
            "White_Russian" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ;
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, CocktailDetail.class);
        ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name","bloodymary");
        startActivity(ourIntent);

    };
}
```

CocktailDetail class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


    public class CocktailDetail extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.cocktaildetail);
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCocktail);
            imageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bloodymary));
            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYoutube);
            TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
            String cocktailName = "Bloody Mary";
            t1.setText(cocktailName);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alt-ehDc3fc")));
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/beer"
    android:id="@+id/cocktailDetail" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCocktailName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Cocktail Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCocktail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bloodymary" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textIngredients"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Insert txt here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Preparation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPrepration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Insert txt here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonYoutube"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="YouTube Clip"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check my comment under this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16078373/1329126 dude. I think you are going to complete each and every line of your application by our help. There are plenty of resources available on the internet for listview. We have already said this in your old question but you are creating a new question for simple bugs. Really you should study something

Answer (score 0):

In Menu class, you are passing hard coded string :

```
   ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name",**"bloodymary"**);
```

Change this to the value retrieved from the ListView :

```
    String selectedFromList =(String) (l.getItemAtPosition(position));
    ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name",selectedFromList);
```

Also in Cocktail Class, `OnCreate`, again you are setting text to hardcoded string. Using `Bundle`, retrieve the value and then setText;

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

 //Extract the data…
 String name = bundle.getString(“cocktail_name”); 
 TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
 t1.setText(name);
```

Comment: ok so I should change it to ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name",Bloody Mary); and then use bundle to retrieve the text. Dou you know how to do it for the photo too?

Comment: Second argument in `putExtra` is the string that contains item selected form list in your case. I have added this in code above. Check it.

Comment: Thanks a mill how would I change the image dynamically here is my code so far

            `String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("cocktail_name");
            TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
            t1.setText(cocktailName);
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCocktail);
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bloodymary);
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cocktailName);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Menu activity:

```
// React to user clicks on item
```

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                         long id) {


     // here you get the Item selected using position

   Intent i = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, CocktailDetails.class);

   i.putExtra("title", your_title_cocktail);

   startActivity(i);
 }
```

});

in the DetailActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
 Intent i = getIntent(); 
---
```

}

give a look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/passing-data-between-activities.html) and [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/listviewpart-1.html).